# Category-theoretic constructions for powerset construction in set theory

Tags: category-theory

Set theory has fundamental constructions such as the [powerset](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/power+set). What is universal construction in the category-theoretic foundation for this construction ? Any reference for other set fundamental constructions ?

Comment: That is a particular case of an exponential object.

Comment: Could you also name some other set constructions ? Are they all have associated constructions ?

Comment: @StefanPerko This was my first thought after googling 'power set universal property' but we have to specify the $2$ object which I guess is the binary direct sum of the terminal object if we were to try to generalize this beyond $\bf{Set}$? Thoughts?

Comment: @basket: may some subsets be intersected, correct ?

Comment: @basket $1+1 = 2$. (no joke intended)

Comment: Im trying to think of how to extend this to categories other than Set. How else can we define 1 generally other than as the point-like terminal object (provided it exists) and how to define addition other than as the coproduct. Is there a more natural way? Or is this universal property not meaningful in other categories? For instance it's a worthless construction in abelian categories.

Comment: @basket That's what I had in mind. Of course, I don't quite know what to do with this. Then again: Powersets are actually certain posets, perhaps "poset" ("preset") "of subobjects" is a more interesting construction.

Comment: @Stefan, subobject is the construction mentioned in my link of my question. But I am more interested in the answers to universal constructions. If you address it with universal ones, I can vote up your answers.

Comment: Ah, also I'm forgetting something important: Subobject classifiers.

Comment: I'm out of my knowledge here but it looks like the power object is the appropriate construction all along.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an overview of how certain categorical constructions generalize set-theoretic ones:

- cartesian products $\prod_{i\in I} A_i$ are generalized by products
- disjoint unions $\sum_{i\in I} A_i$ are generalized by coproducts
- sets $B^A$ of functions $A \to B$ is generalized by exponentials
- sets of equivalence classes are generalized by coequalizers of (internal) congruences
- the empty set is generalized by initial objects
- singletons are generalized by terminal objects
- two-element sets may be generalized by $1+1$, where $1$ is a terminal object and $+$ is a coproduct; or by subobject classifiers

The powerset can be generalized as an exponential $X^A$ where $X = 1 + 1$ or $X$ is a subobject classifier. This would be an *internal* generalization.

On the other hand, a powerset can also be generalized *externally* by the preset/poset $\operatorname{Sub} A$ of subobjects of an object $A$. Then:

- unions $\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i$ are generalized by suprema in $\operatorname{Sub} A$ (if $A_i \subseteq A$)
- intersections $\bigcap_{i\in I} A_i$ are generalized by infima in $\operatorname{Sub} A$ (if $A_i \subseteq A$)

Comment: $\Omega = 2$ only happens in special cases.

Comment: @Hurkyl Right, I should not have called it "$2$".

Comment: @StefanPerko, Can you add generalization of limit/colimit, representable functor, adjoint functor, end/coend, Kan extension, dependent sum/dependent product ?

Comment: @Tom ... uhm. All of these are adjoints, all of these are representables, all of these are Kan extensions and all of these are limits / colimits. And they are countless ways to generalize all of these too. That's a bit to broad to answer and in any case should be a seperate question, I think.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer from Stefan, the notion of power object generalizes the notion of power set from the category **Set** to an arbitrary category with finite limits. If $1$ is a terminal object, then the power object is precisely a subobject classifier. A power object in **Set** is precisely a power set. A category with finite limits and power objects for all objects is precisely a topos. The power object $PA$ for any object $A$ in the typos is the exponential object into the subject classifier.